# Как осуществляется делегирование по цепочке [[prototype]] в данном примере?

Tags: javascript, объекты, prototype

```js
var docs = {
  a: 20,
  foo: function() {
    return this.a * 10
  }
};

var amg = Object.create(docs);
amg.a = 10;

var ags = Object.create(amg).foo();

document.write(ags)
```

Насчёт  вызова `Object.create(amg).foo()`:

1) Создаётся пустой объект

2) Его свойствy `[[prototype]]` даётся ссылка на `amg`

3) Из этого ***пустого*** объекта вызывается метод `foo()`, но данного метода у этого объекта нет, поэтому исследуется цепочка `prototype`, в связи с чем, данный метод находится в объекте `docs`?

*Вопрос в том, как осуществляется поиск именно свойства `а`?*

Я так понял по той же, описанной выше схеме? Т.е. интерпретатор (как я описал выше) вызывает метод `foo()` так, как будто он есть в `Object.create(amg)` и сталкивается с тем, что у данного пустого объекта нет собственного свойства `а`, поэтому снова запускается поиск по его цепочке прототипов?

*Получается интерпретатор выполняет два "прохода" по цепочке `[[prototype]]` данного объекта `Object.create(amg)`, чтобы выполнить операцию присваивания `var ags = . . .`?*

Comment: _Получается интерпретатор выполняет два "прохода" по цепочке_ - в общем случае да, но может зависеть от конкретной реализации.

Comment: @Grundy понятно!